# jQuery: Run AJAX every X seconds for only 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run AJAX for lets say every 5 seconds and then stop the whole ajax call after 60 seconds so there won't be any ajax call every 5 seconds after we reached the 60 seconds.

I'm not sure if this is possible at all!

I can easily run my ajax every 5 seconds like so:

```
    setInterval(function(){ 

 $.ajax({url: 'PHP-PAGE.php', success: function(result){

    }});

     }, 5000);
```

Is there any way to start the 60 seconds count down within the ajax and stop the whole ajax call after we reached the 60 seconds?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Capture the process id from your set interval

```
var intervalID = setInterval(..., 5000)
```

Then immediately set a timeout that will cancel the interval in 60 seconds

```
setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(intervalID)},60000)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    if(new Date().getTime() - start > 60000) { // 60 seconds
        clearInterval(interval)
        interval =null;
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({url: 'PHP-PAGE.php', success: function(result){
        ...
    }});
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Please reformat your code - other than that I think this is a better solution than the (currently) higher voted one because it takes true time into account in a way that `setInterval` sometimes does not.

Comment: @Alnitak could you elaborate what makes this better in your opinion? I'm not sure I understand your point because both solutions use `setInterval` to trigger the Ajax.

Comment: @BeetleJuice `setInterval` events can end up queued (e.g. if the browser is busy) and then events get released all in one go.  Having the check against elapsed time ensures that the primary constraint of "nothing happens after 60 seconds" is honoured.

Comment: Interesting.  If `clearInterval` is called while a `setInterval` event is queued, do you know whether the queue is cleared or executed?

Comment: @BeetleJuice it will be cleared

Comment: Then I still don't get the concern you raised.  If `clearInterval` will clear the queue, how does the highly rated answer not ensure the primary constraint of "nothing happens after 60 seconds"? It uses one `setTimeout` to clear the interval 60 seconds after the `setInterval` call.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is a bad practice to execute asynchronous calls inside a `setInterval` function. Instead, you could execute the same function from it's callback, after a **timeout**:

**EXAMPLE**

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/QsHw4/7111/) for a working example.

---

**EDIT (Added response time calculation)**

```
// Start a counter
var i = 0;
var start = setInterval(function() { i++; }, 1000);

var ajaxCall = function() {

   // Set the start time
   var startAjaxRequest = new Date().getTime();

   // Execute ajax call
   $.ajax({url: 'PHP-PAGE.php', success: function(result){

      // Get the ajax response time in ms
      var ajaxResponseTime = new Date().getTime() - startAjaxRequest;

      if (i < 60 && ajaxResponseTime < 5000) {

         // Execute the same ajax call after 5 seconds minus ajax response time
         setTimeout(ajaxCall, 5000 - ajaxResponseTime);

      } else {

         clearInterval(start);

      }
   }});
}
```

Comment: I agree with the principle of using `setTimeout` in a loop instead of `setInterval`, but why then use a separate counter to measure elapsed time?!

Comment: p.s. you should also just use `setTimeout(ajaxCall, 5000)` without the additional anonymous function wrapper

Comment: This doesn't meet the OP's requirement "I'm trying to run AJAX for lets say every 5 seconds".  The Ajax call in this solution is not triggered on a predictable schedule.  By the way I'm interested. Why is it bad practice to execute asynchronous calls inside a `setInterval`?

Comment: Because, when you call an asynchronous function, you can not be sure about the response time. If the response comes back in less time that the next async call, it's ok, but in the other way, the next async call will be executed before the previous response is available.

Comment: I see. I guess it depends on requirements. If the OP stated the problem in exact terms (meaning that requests should be triggered every 5 seconds) then this solution won't work. On the other hand, if what the OP wants is for the next request to be made 5 secs after the last is received, this is better.  With a bit of work, the OP can even get the best of both worlds with use of an additional flag: trigger every 5 seconds, but skip if the last result hasn't come in yet. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Another solution would be this: calculate the response time and call the next async call after 5 second minus this time (if the response takes less that 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You should add time counter

```
var timeCounter= 0;
```

and then check if it above 60s in your `setInterval` call

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    timeCounter += 5;
    if (timeCounter > 60) {
        clearInterval(interval);

    } else {
        $.ajax({url: 'PHP-PAGE.php', success: function(result){

        }});
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Shouldn't the `timeCounter` increment occur at the start?  As things are, When time elapsed is 65 seconds, the check `if(timeCounter > 60)` will fail because the counter would be equal to 60 (from the previous function call)

Comment: It should, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an easiest way. May helpful to you:

```js
 $(function() {
   var tick = 1;
   setInterval(function() {
  if (tick <= 12) { // set how much times that you want to repeat
    $.ajax({
   url: 'http://date.jsontest.com',
   success: function(result) {
     $('pre').append('hi ' + tick + '</br>');
     tick = tick + 1;
   }
    });
  }
   }, 5000); // interval time 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure it meets one of the requirements. The OP wrote: " there won't be any ajax call...after we reached the 60 seconds."  By incrementing the `tick` in the `onSuccess` callback, you lose control over whether the tick actually keeps time.  If a call triggered around 55 secs takes a while to respond and 5 seconds go by, it will fail to increment `tick` in time and another call will be made beyond the 60 secs limit

Comment: @BeetleJuice yes. I agree with your point also. If OP doesn't want to execute any ajax calls after 60th second, then this method won't helpful to the OP. If OP wants to make 12 ajax requests, i.e. `12*5=60` seconds, then he can use this.

Comment: downvoters should need to leave a comment why the answer is downvoted.

Comment: I agree. I think Stack should require a comment with each down vote (the same way justification is required when topics are put on hold), even if those comments are shown separately from this comment thread. It would help people write better answers.

Comment: A good discussion over this went [here in meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284769/authority-to-downvote-without-comment)

Answer (score -1):

check the code below :)

```
for(var i = 1; i < 61; i++) {
   setTimeout(function(){
     console.log('#afucntionthatrunseverysecondinoneminute')
   },1000*i);
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient I think, and memory intensive, because you're asking the browser to track 60 processes at once when 1 or 2 could be used to solve the problem.

Comment: 0.724 ms in my browser

Comment: @Guti even so, it's not good practise

Comment: @Alnitak, yeah you're right. But it is handy sometimes :)

Comment: No, it's not handy, it's lazy